# CMS pages linked to from 2nd level category pages include category path in url and give 404

Tags: url, cms, 404, cms-pages, magento2.1.5

CMS pages (such as about-us, privacy-policy etc) link fine from root domain (such as domain.co.uk) and from domain.co.uk/category1.html.  In this instance then the correct URL is domain.co.uk/about-us and the about-us page is displayed.

However when navigating to CMS pages from 2nd level category URL's (domain.co.uk/category1/category2.html), the link is domain.co.uk/category1/category2/about-us, and this generates a 404 page as the page doesn't exist.

What is the solution to this?

I'm using Magento 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I think in magento static block your directly using **'/about-us'** , 
Instead of that try to use below code in href of your link:

```
href="{{store url="about-us"}}"
```

If your code is in template level then use below code for href:

```
$baseurl = $this->getBaseUrl();
href="<?php echo $baseurl.'about-us' ?>"
```

Same You can edit href to other static page links!